# Android Facebook Messenger intent not working

Tags: android

im trying to share audio file on facebook messenger. Following as mention https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android#integration_with_intents here but it work to share simple text not audio file. App crash when i try to send audio on messenger.

This is intent share code
    String mimeType = "audio/aac";

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROTOCOL_VERSION, PROTOCOL_VERSION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_ID);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, SHARE_TO_MESSENGER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: What is the exact error trace?

Comment: intent not opening it stopped and logcat show nothing

Answer (score -1):

There is no option for Facebook, but you can share email and MMS with Bluetooth. Here is my code. Take a look if it helps you:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+mypath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i succeed in sharing audio files on facebook messenger. my code is correct the only problem was with the path URI. is was converteing absolute path to uri due to which is was crashing but when convert file path to uri it working correct